# Jenkins Plugin that Aggregates/Summarizes Reports for a Build

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I'm searching for an existing Jenkins plugin or something close to it. This is my ideal:

- Provides a link to the side on a build page
- Clicking the link will open up a page with a summary of the various reports (ideally configured)

  - Reports could include:

    - Cobertura
    - Surefire
    - Static analysis
    - Security
    - Other
  - There will be links to the full report pages from the other plugins as well as a few columns providing basic info like Status, Details, and another column or two maybe

This seems basic enough that I would think it already exists, but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing [Cobertura](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cobertura+Plugin), [JUnit](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin) and various [Static Analysis plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin) for Jenkins will already add links to each build page, pointing to a summary of the results of each tool.

For other tools, you can use the [HTML Publisher plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin) to add more links to each build page.

But I don't believe there is another plugin which will build some sort of summary from a list of arbitrary reports.